# Images are not displaying in Facebook Share

Tags: facebook, share

I am using facebook sharer.php, to share a link from my site to the facebook wall. Following is the url, I am using to get this done.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=**title_to_be_shared**&p[url]=**link_to_be_shared**&p[images][0]=**image_path**
I am aware that sharer.php is deprecated.  But I have searched a lot to implement this share feature.  I found only this.  But in this,  the images are not rendered properly in all cases.  In some cases the images are not loading while sharing.

Please help me to overcome this.  Or if there is another API to get this done please let me know...

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Raju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sharer.php method is deprecated and no longer supported. As far as I can tell, the best replacement for sharing a page of your site is the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).